# using embed src in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, embed

I am storing a movie (.swf) file in sql server db.
In my aspx page I can get the blob(varbinary) and also the filename.
photo1 is the actual movie field; photo1name is the filename stored in db.

I am trying to play this movie in my aspx page using this code:

```
 <param name="movie" value="photo1name">

 <embed src="photo1name" width="550" height="400"></embed>
```

I realize the passing the movie file as string to value= and src= are wrong.
Can some one help me correct the mistake?

thanks and regards
krishna

Comment: Can you please post your code here?

Comment: Already code posted - two lines of code.

Comment: Well, if you want it to get from database, you should have code behind code also.

Comment: Why are you storing a movie in a database?

Answer (score 0):

You either need to serve the file from the database to the client. A custom handler comes to mind.

Or you could base64 encode it in Code Behind and send it in the Page response.

But if it is a very large movie, I strongly suggest you serve it via a custom handler.